# ¿Cual es la Forma correcta de cerrar una activity?

Tags: java, android-studio

Cuando paso de una activity a otra, utilizo el siguiente codigo. Utilizo el finish para cerrar la activity de donde salgo ya que no la necesito mas y para liberar memoria.

Preguntas:

1. ¿Es la forma correcta o hay una mejor, el finish() si borra la activity de la memoria y de la pila?
2. ¿Uso esta transicion para pasar entre mis activitys, me pueden recomendar otras transiciones o una  pagina donde pueda ver otras opciones?

Gracias

```
public void opciones(View view) {

    Intent opciones = new Intent(principal.this, segunda.class);
    startActivity(opciones);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in, R.anim.left_out);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Lo que realizas es definitivamente lo correcto Isabel. Trata en lo posible de agregar una pregunta en lugar de varias :D

Answer (score 2):

**Para cerrar una activity la forma correcta es usar [finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finish())**

> [finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finish()) Llámelo cuando termine su actividad y debería cerrarse.
> El ActivityResult se propaga a quien lo lanzó a través de
> onActivityResult().

al invocar este mètodo, la activity se prepara para ser eliminada de la memoria y por lo tanto de la pila.

Al llamar a [finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finish()) en una actividad, se ejecuta el método `onDestroy()`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Para pasar entre Actividades la forma correcta es usar el `Intent`:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Revisa : [**Como iniciar otra actividad**](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity)